# How to use predefined/ trained (hdf5) file with wights to predict a class of new eeg data?

Tags: python, model, classification, keras, theano

I have a predefined file called (bestmodel.hdf5), which is created using Keras library (python) and theano

The trained model using the following code.

```
# set parameters
batch_size = 1280
nb_epoch = 3000 #6000
l1_decay=0.00
l2_decay=0 # .5
# 0.01  0.06
sigma=0.005
in_drop_rate = .2
drop_rate = .5

print (tr_X.shape[1])
# set network layout
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2184, input_shape=(tr_X.shape[1],)
                , init='he_normal', W_regularizer=l1_l2(l1=l1_decay, l2=l2_decay)))
model.add(GaussianNoise(sigma))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(in_drop_rate))


model.add(Dense(1310, init='he_normal', W_regularizer=l1_l2(l1=l1_decay, l2=l2_decay)))
model.add(GaussianNoise(sigma))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(drop_rate))

model.add(Dense(786, init='he_normal', W_regularizer=l1_l2(l1=l1_decay, l2=l2_decay)))
model.add(GaussianNoise(sigma))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(drop_rate))

model.add(Dense(472, init='he_normal', W_regularizer=l1_l2(l1=l1_decay, l2=l2_decay)))
model.add(GaussianNoise(sigma))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(drop_rate))


model.add(Dense(4, W_regularizer=l1_l2(l1=l1_decay, l2=l2_decay)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

# Callbacks
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.hdf5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)
early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=600, verbose=0)

# fit and evaluate the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001))#SGD(lr=0.0019, momentum=0.9, decay=0.0, nesterov=True))
history = model.fit(tr_X, tr_y, batch_size=batch_size,
                    nb_epoch=nb_epoch, verbose=0,  callbacks=[early, model_checkpoint],
                    validation_data=(va_X, va_y))
model.load_weights('best_model.hdf5')
tr_pr = model.predict(tr_X, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
```

However, to test a real data (form experiment), I have a different sizes as input (ex. instead of 2184 , I have 552)

Thus, to read the hdf5 weight file and use it to predict the class of the data. I wrote the following:

```
# set parameters
batch_size = 4
l1_decay=0.00
l2_decay=0 # .5
# 0.01  0.06
sigma=0.005
in_drop_rate = .2
drop_rate = .5

# set network layout
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(552, input_shape=(552,)
                , init='he_normal', W_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=l1_decay, l2=l2_decay)))
model.add(GaussianNoise(sigma))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(in_drop_rate))


model.add(Dense(331, init='he_normal', W_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=l1_decay, l2=l2_decay)))
model.add(GaussianNoise(sigma))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(drop_rate))

model.add(Dense(189, init='he_normal', W_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=l1_decay, l2=l2_decay)))
model.add(GaussianNoise(sigma))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(drop_rate))

model.add(Dense(119, init='he_normal', W_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=l1_decay, l2=l2_decay)))
model.add(GaussianNoise(sigma))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(drop_rate))

model.add(Dense(4, W_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=l1_decay, l2=l2_decay)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))


model.load_weights('best_model.hdf5')
te_pr = model.predict(X, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
```

When I run the code, I got the following exception:

```
C:\Users\M\Desktop\Dr Abeer Folder\Emotion Project_code and dataset\End User\Experiment_Calculation.py:106: UserWarning: Update your `Dense` call to the Keras 2 API: `Dense(119, kernel_regularizer=<keras.reg..., kernel_initializer="he_normal")`

model.add(Dense(119, init='he_normal', W_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=l1_decay, l2=l2_decay)))


C:\Users\M\Desktop\Dr Abeer Folder\Emotion Project_code and dataset\End User\Experiment_Calculation.py:112: UserWarning: Update your `Dense` call to the Keras 2 API: `Dense(4, kernel_regularizer=<keras.reg...)`

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\M\Desktop\Dr Abeer Folder\Emotion Project_code and dataset\End User\main2.py", line 88, in BrowseFileHandler

expcal.calclate_Experiment()

File "C:\Users\M\Desktop\Dr Abeer Folder\Emotion Project_code and dataset\End User\Experiment_Calculation.py", line 66, in calclate_Experiment

predictions = DNN(X)

File "C:\Users\M\Desktop\Dr Abeer Folder\Emotion Project_code and dataset\End User\Experiment_Calculation.py", line 117, in DNN

te_pr = model.predict(X, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)

File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 902, in predict

return self.model.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)

File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1585, in predict

batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)

File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1212, in _predict_loop

batch_outs = f(ins_batch)

File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py", line 1158, in __call__

return self.function(*inputs)

File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 898, in __call__

storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))

File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\theano\gof\link.py", line 325, in raise_with_op

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)

File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 884, in __call__

self.fn() if output_subset is None else\

ValueError: dimension mismatch in args to gemm (4,552)x(2184,2184)->(4,2184)

Apply node that caused the error: GpuDot22(GpuFromHost.0, dense_1/kernel)

Toposort index: 28

Inputs types: [CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix), CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix)]

Inputs shapes: [(4, 552), (2184, 2184)]

Inputs strides: [(552, 1), (2184, 1)]

Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']

Outputs clients: [[GpuElemwise{Add}[(0, 0)](GpuDot22.0, 
GpuDimShuffle{x,0}.0), GpuElemwise{Composite{(i0 + i1 + (i2 * i3))}}[(0, 3)]
(GpuDot22.0, GpuDimShuffle{x,0}.0, CudaNdarrayConstant{[[ 0.005]]}, GpuReshape{2}.0)]]



HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.

HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.


model.add(Dense(4, W_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=l1_decay, l2=l2_decay)))
```

Can anyone, please help in understanding th problem. I'm new in the area especially with the using of the Keras, and theano? How can I fix it ? Is there a way to change the model for predection ?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward.

You trained a model that was, for the first layer, a 2184x2184 matrix. So the weight you saved were trained for a 2184 input and they were adapted to the kind of input you were training on.

If I understand correctly you would like to apply this matrix to a 552 length input... You are building a model where your first layer is a 552x552 matrix and you want to load a 2184x2184 matrix into it... There is just no way to do that... It's not going to work, your input should be the same size exactly. You cannot change a trained model.

I hope you understand why it will not work :-) If not, please ask for clarifications

Comment: Thanks @NassimBen for the answer. I got but I want to do the reverse (model is trained on 2184 x 2184, while the test input (for predection) is 552x552). I got the answer after I traied to enlarge the input to have the same size as the required size of the model and it works. Thus, for now I'm trying to make the trained and the tested data with the same size. So, I will not face such a problem.